# Armature current control of DC motor

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, dc-motor

In DC motor speed control, we usually build an inner current loop that serves to control the armature current so the speed/torque of the motor.

[image]

Let's assume that we want to control the speed of a DC motor in one direction using a PWM signal and a switch (transistor), the topology may be high side or low side control:

[image]

My first questions are:

1. Which topology is best to control the armature current of the DC motor?
2. In a high side control, the configuration looks like a buck converter, and in low side control, the configuration looks like flyback converter, so in both cases, how do we control the armature current? Do we use voltage mode PWM to generate the PWM signal or is it preferebale to use current mode PWM control to generate PWM signal?

[image]

[image]

I want you to focus on the way the PWM is generated, In here I have adopted the voltage mode PWM model to control the current through the inductor, and I have done an analogy to voltage mode, continuous current buck converter.

Here are the graphs I got from simulation:

[image]

The output current seems to me to be nice and well tunned (Iout=4A)

The AC analysis of the system is given below:

[image]

The bode plots of PWM_gain, chopper_gain and PI_controller gain are shown below:

- PI Bode plot

[image]

- Chopper Bode plot

[image]

- PWM_Modulator Bode plot

[image]

- Could anyone explain to me the shattering of the PWM Modulator and its effect on the stability of the whole system? and how to evoid that shattering ?

Comment: you say, 'control the armature current, so the speed of the motor'. Do you mean 'control the armature current, so the torque of the motor'. Current controls torque, which eventually through acceleration influences speed. However, if you hold current constant, the motor can run at any speed, with a near constant torque. High side and low side control are trivially equivalent, and are both buck, that naturally controls voltage, which will tend to run a DC motor at constant speed (voltage). If you want to control current, you need to sense it to control it.

Comment: Be aware that the equivalent "DC motor model" is not what you have designed...

Comment: @Neil_UK, when we look to loop speed control, we see that the reference current is generated by speed reference and that current generates the adequate current to acheive the desired speed. This is why I said "'control the armature current, so the speed of the motor". It is not a direct control, but it is indirect, as you said "However, if you hold current constant, the motor can run at any speed, with a near constant torque". Of course we have to sense the current and this is the key. I have updated my question and the graphs to clarify my idea.

Comment: @Antonio51, I have modeled the electrical part and I set Ea (Back emf ) constant just for simulation, and the mechanical part is not modeled since I'm interested on control of the armature current and not the whole system, at least in this post.

Comment: What's the PWM frequency, is it about 20 kHz by any chance, or maybe 10? You're going through your corner frequency at about 1 kHz, all else above that is just froth as far as stability is concerned. 'Shattered' is a good word to describe what happens if you sample a rapidly changing curve too infrequently - it's called aliasing if done in the other domain. At the cost of run time, do the analysis on a much much finer grid, and you'll see meaningful detail in the traces, so those gain nulls you see at decade boundaries, you're not seeing them at nx10kHz because you're missing a point there.

Comment: @Neil_UK The saw tooth frequency is 1kHz

Comment: which will explain the nulls and phase inversions at 2 kHz (or would be nulls if you sampled on them) and its harmonics